# Form redirect to same page, but showing that not exist

Tags: html, wordpress, forms

Hello I have a really strange problem with html form. I am using Wordpress and I created my custom html form. When i submit the form it redirects me on the same page url, but showing me that the page doesnt exist.

My form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control input-text" placeholder="Vaše jméno a příjmení" />
                        <div class="validation"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control input-text" name="email" placeholder="Váš e-mail" />
                        <div class="validation"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" name="subject" placeholder="Předmět zprávy" />
                        <div class="validation"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control input-text text-area" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Vaše zpráva pro nás..."></textarea>
                        <div class="validation"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- Google reCAPTCHA widget -->
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                            <!-- recaptcha here -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4" style="padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0;">
                            <div class="text-center" style="margin-right: 7px;"><button name="submit" style="width: 135px; height: 75px; padding:0 !important;" type="submit" class="input-btn">Odeslat</button></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I tried to hide all my php code behind, also hide google recaptcha, but nothing works and the problem is elsewhere. My action is also empty, just set method.

What is wrong, any suggestions?

Comment: "but showing me that the page doesnt exist" as in 404? Or is it because it doesn't accept a POST?

Comment: 404 error, i have custom page showing 404 error. I have not experience with forms in Wordpress so iam not sure if its okay to do this like that

Comment: Have you tried to leave out action="" ?

Comment: `action=""` is an invalid setup for forms. Just omit the action attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the name of your field `name="name"` to something else.
for more information you can read here
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11749/why-when-i-submit-a-form-in-wordpress-it-loads-a-404-page-though-url-is-correct

Comment: Thank you so much, save my today to be honest

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is the `submit` button.

When you create a form, the submit button is an `input` as well.

You may try

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" yourtags="yourvalue">
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp for more data.

EDIT: if you are trying to send the action to the same page, omit the `action` attribute. Perhaps leaving it blank causes an error.

Comment: <button type="submit"> also submits the form, so <input> and <button> should be interchangeable in this case

Comment: Had no idea. I've only been teached to do it as an input. Then the problem is either the action attribute or something else